# MySQL query pulls data from another row than specified

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that pulls the lowest number of `listNumber` for every `companyId` from a given `searchId` where the date is newer than a specified date. So I would get one row for each company containing the data of the row with the lowest `listNumber` of all entries from that company.

The (simplified) MySQL table is like this:

```
id          (PK) 
companyId   (int) 
searchId    (int) 
productName (varchar) 
effective   (decimal) 
listNumber  (int) 
addedWhen   (timestamp)
```

`companyId` and `searchId` are linked to the PKs of two other tables.

I've tried something like

```
SELECT MIN(listNumber) AS listnumber, bankId, productName, effective 
FROM DummyTableName 
WHERE addedWhen >= '2011-04-05 00:00:00' 
AND searchId='26' 
GROUP BY companyId
```

but with no luck as this will return the lowest `listNumber`, but all other data will be taken from another row with the same `companyId`.

Any ideas on how I can get this query right?

Comment: what is bankId? Maybe you mean companyId.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Yes bankId is companyId, correcting it now

Comment: How do you know the solution is simple if you don't know what it is? o.O Statements like that baffle me.

Comment: @Tomalak hehe ok, le me reformulate that then;) I got a feeling it's simple, but it might also be the most complex thing ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 
  JOIN (SELECT companyId, MIN(listNumber) min_listNumber FROM table
    WHERE addedWhen >= '2011-04-05 00:00:00' AND searchId='26'
    GROUP BY companyId) t2
  ON t1.companyId = t2.companyId AND t1.listnumber = t2.min_listnumber
WHERE t1.addedWhen >= '2011-04-05 00:00:00' AND t1.searchId='26';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... HAVING Something = MIN(Something)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
select listnumber,bankid,productname, effective 
from dummytablename
left join (SELECT MIN(listNumber) AS listnumber, bankId 
FROM DummyTableName 
WHERE addedWhen >= '2011-04-05 00:00:00' 
AND searchId='26' group by bankid) as t where dummytablename.listnumber=t.listnumber and dummytablename.bankid=t.bankid
```

But its kinda ugly (Im sure I've used a better solution than this)

Answer (score 0):

If you group by everything but the aggregate function field it should work.  You should only need HAVING in this case if you were getting a count or sum of a field and wanted to display that count/sum.

```
SELECT MIN(listNumber) AS listnumber, bankId, productName, effective 
FROM DummyTableName 
WHERE addedWhen >= '2011-04-05 00:00:00' 
AND searchId='26' 
GROUP BY bankId, productName, effective
```